recent php upgrade causing SESSION problems
Recently my host made an upgrade to php version 8.2.17 from 8.1.27 .   This caused big problems with all my sites that uses SESSIONS.  I have session_start() as my first line of php and I get the following error.  It works perfectly on the previous version
error:  [13-Apr-2024 09:58:28 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  session_start(): open(/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php82/sess_706b28cdc09846ab8d66fcdebce8c600, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /home1/webpacka/public_html/index.php on line 4
[13-Apr-2024 09:58:28 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path: /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php82) in /home1/webpacka/public_html/index.php on line 4
my only fix is to switch back to the older version, which was suggested by my hosting tech, along with you should contact your programmer.  Any ideas?  Permission problem?
